# Angular - How can I add amounts in a button?

Tags: angular, button, angular-material, cart

My problem is, that I can't add amounts in a button.

My code looks like this:

**navbar.component.html:**

```
<button>0,00$</button>
<button function="onClick()">Add 5</button>
```

and

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss'],
})
export class NavbarComponent {

  onClick(){
    //add 5 when clicked
  }


}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out. I can't get it to work that if I click on the button with the function, that I can add 5$ to the other button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try=>
**HTML:**

```
<button>{{sumValue}}</button>
<button (click)="onClick()">Add 5</button>
```

**TS:**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  sumValue:number=0;
  onClick(){
    this.sumValue=this.sumValue+5;
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to ask but is it possible to use the onClick() function also for other components so they work across? For example if my navbar.component.html contains the button and the body.component.ts should contain the onClick() function, is that possible? I would so thankful if you could reply.